# PHP script returning JSON not working

Tags: php, json

The below returns "\nQuery was empty" as I run it simply from my server with the URL in the Browser.

This is the PHP code:

```
    <?

$databasehost = "server";
$databasename = "xxxx";
$databaseusername ="xxxx";
$databasepassword = "xxxx";
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `Tailor`LIMIT 0 , 30";
$con = mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());
$query = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$sth = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_errno()) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo $query.'\n';
    echo mysql_error(); 
}
else
{
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use file_get_content and you have to put one white space after table name.

```
<?php

$databasehost = "server";
$databasename = "xxxx";
$databaseusername ="xxxx";
$databasepassword = "xxxx";
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `Tailor` LIMIT 0 , 30";
$con = mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());

$sth = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_errno()) { 
header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
echo $query.'\n';
echo mysql_error(); 
}
else
{
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a problem you need whitespace after tablename

```
SELECT * FROM  `Tailor` LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: cured it BUT still the same

Comment: WHy are you sing this $query = file_get_contents("php://input");?

Comment: i removed it was not needed nw im watching out for result

Comment: Okay let me know the outcome

Answer (score 0):

first

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `Tailor`LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

but you overwrite it

```
$query = file_get_contents("php://input"); 

// $query like   aaa=ggg&bbb=kkk
```

then you

```
$sth = mysql_query($query);

// LIKE $sth = mysql_query('aaa=bbb&ccc=lll'); //it not sql query format
```